# Disabling figure numbering in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

Is it possible to use figure captions (i.e., `fig.cap`) but without numbering, that is, with neither "Figure", nor the number shown in `bookdown`?

The best solution would be one that works for all output formats (say, `gitbook`, `pdf_book` and `epub_book`).